# 404 on new asp.net web api, after route config is setup

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller which works perfectly fine:

```
   [Authorize]
    [Route("api/Version")]
    public class VersionController : ApiController
    {
```

However if I omit the Route attribute in other controllers it doesnt work, when I go to: url/api/User or Users, I get a 404

```
  [Authorize]
    public class UserController : ApiController
    {
```

my webappi config

```
  public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
                        
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );


            config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new AiExceptionLogger());
        }
    }
```

my routeconfig

```
  public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

User Controller GetUsers

```
  [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUsers()
        {
```

Comment: Show the signature of the action method and the related URLs you are trying.

Comment: https://xyz.azurewebsites.net/api/User or https://xyz.azurewebsites.net/api/Users

Comment: @Luis Valencia: Did you call `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);` before  `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);`?

Comment: I dont have GlobalConfiguration.Configure somewhere on my code

Comment: You didn't show the action method. Does it have a `Route` or `HttpGet` attribute?

Comment: just updated the question at the end

Comment: you attempted GET `api/User/GetUsers` as well?

Comment: The action is called `GetUsers` so that should be part of the URL unless you change it with an attribute.

Comment: going to link this resource, I'm not exactly sure this is expected behavior for determining action.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection#action-selection   I suspect you have more then 1 method with `HttpGet` attribute defined

Comment: Okay, so you don't have GlobalConfiguration.Configure. Where do you invoke WebApiConfig.Register?

Comment: hold on, I found this line on the global.asax.cs   GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

Comment: Can you reproduce it on a new , clean project? The code seems correct so there is something you don't show us. Is it possible that your user controller doesn't inherit from ApiController but from Controller? Is there another MVC UserController. If there was a problem with the routes you'd probably get something other than a 404. Show us the entire UserController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be defining two different configuration classes that specify different route schemes in their methods:

- In `WebApiConfig.Register(...)`, you have `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"`;
- In `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(...)`, you specified `url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"`.
  Please note that these routes overlap each other, so you have to be careful when employing these configurations in your application.

Regarding the `VersionController` and `UserController`, it seems that it is in fact the `Route` attribute that is defining your route.

In `VersionController`, if you specify `[Route("api/Version")]`, you are correctly able to access `/api/version`. If you remove this, you may be able to access `/version` instead of `/api/version`, or are you not? (This may help understanding what configuration - `WebApiConfig`, `RouteConfig` or any - is used.

Likewise, in `UserController`, given that you don't specify `[Route("api/User")]`, you may be able to access `/user` (without the `/api` prefix). Can you confirm this, please? On the other hand, if you were defining the `Route` attribute, then you should be able to access `api/user`.

I am assuming that you are already mapping your controllers to endpoints, since I understood that you are able to access `api/version`.

This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0) is pretty good on explaining Routing in MVC projects (in this case, for .NET Core), and it explians the multiple routes approach that perhaps you are trying to achieve with `WebApiConfig` and `RouteConfig`.

Comment: amazing explanation, I will check and if it works accept the answer, if not I will post a comment hhere.